# Enabling amd_pstate in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: drivers, kernel

Is there any documentation on how to enable the new `amd_pstate` driver in Ubuntu 22.10? I've seen a couple [posts](https://www.phoronix.com/news/AMD-P-State-How-To) that talk about blacklisting the default `acpi-cpufreq` driver, a post that says it's [on by default](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/amd-p-state-in-kernel-5-17-oem/27275/4), and another that mentions that there might be [incoming patches](https://www.phoronix.com/news/AMD-Easier-P-State-Usage) in kernel 5.18/5.19 to make switching it on easier.

As someone who doesn't touch the kernel much, I'd like to improve my computer's battery life if I can but just want to double-check to see whether there's any up-to-date Ubuntu documentation so I can avoid bricking my install.

Comment: to see what CPU frequency scaling driver you are currently using do: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`.

Comment: @DougSmythies `grep: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver: No such file or directory`

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin : is frequency scaling disabled in the BIOS? Note: the feature has different names for different processors and different motherboards, so I can not provide more detail as to where to look.

Comment: @DougSmythies Frequency scaling is on. Just BIOS defaults with PBO and XMP on, 5950X.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin : you should start a new question, detailing your specific issues. It will reach a broader audience, as likely nobody is seeing these comments. I'll watch for it and try to help (but a link to it herein would help). I am not aware of frequency scaling being enabled and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` not existing.

Comment: Kernel 5.18 is not a Ubuntu kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you just have to add `"amd_pstate=passive"` (without the parenthesis) to your kernel parameters, save and close the file, and then issue `sudo update-grub` to rebuild your grub configuration file with the new kernel parameter that you just added. As per the Ubuntu wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters at the bottom of the page it tells you how to properly and permanently add a kernel parameter to your `/etc/default/grub` file.

Here is the relevant section:

Permanently Add a Kernel Boot Parameter
Log in to the system and start a terminal window (Applications->Accessories->Terminal).

In the terminal window at the $ prompt, enter the command: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Enter your password when prompted by [sudo].
If the file `/etc/default/grub` appears to be empty or does not exist, see the instructions for earlier releases above).
In the editor window, use the arrow keys to move the cursor to the line beginning with `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT"` then edit that line, adding your parameter(s) to the text inside the double-quotes after the words `"quiet splash"`. (Be sure to add a SPACE after `"splash"` before adding your new parameter.) Click the Save button, then close the editor window.

In the terminal window at the $ prompt, enter the command: `sudo update-grub`

Restart the system.
Note: The parameter(s) you've added to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line are persistent, and will be in effect for every subsequent boot session (unless you remove them by repeating the procedure above).